# Find the value of $x$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find the value of $x$, $$\left ( \frac{4}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}} \right )^{4-x}=\left ( 80+32\sqrt{6} \right )^{x}$$

any help?

Comment: If you are going to make a *major* edit to your question, worth commenting on it in the question (and on the answers that people have taken the time to write.)

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$(4-x)\ln\frac{4}{\sqrt{3-\sqrt{2}}}=x\ln{(80+32\sqrt 6)}$$

I'm going to just use $a$ and $b$ for simplicity

$$(4-x)a=bx$$
$$4a-ax=bx$$
$$x(a+b)=4a$$
$$x=\frac{4a}{a+b}$$

Resubstitute, voila.

Comment: I'm sorry about the mistake in the question, I did make an edit

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

The big trick is to note that $$80+32\sqrt{6}=16(\sqrt 3+\sqrt 2)^2$$
and
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 3-\sqrt2} = \sqrt3+\sqrt 2$$

So if $z=4(\sqrt3 +\sqrt2)$ this equation is:

$$z^{4-x}=z^{2x}$$

Answer (score 0):

Taking logarithm of both sides:

$$(4-x)\log\left(\frac{4}{\sqrt3-\sqrt2}\right) = x\log\left(80 + 32\sqrt6\right) $$

$$ \frac{4}{\sqrt3-\sqrt2} = \left(\frac{4}{\sqrt3-\sqrt2}\right)\frac{\sqrt3+\sqrt2}{\sqrt3+\sqrt2}=4(\sqrt3+\sqrt2) $$

$$4\log\left(4(\sqrt3+\sqrt2)\right) - x\log\left(4(\sqrt3+\sqrt2)\right) = x\log(80 + 32\sqrt6) = x\log\left(16(\sqrt3+\sqrt2)^2\right) $$

$$ x = \frac{4\log4 + 4\log(\sqrt3 + \sqrt2)}{2\log4 + 2\log(\sqrt3 + \sqrt2) + \log4 + \log(\sqrt3 + \sqrt2)}$$

$$ x =\frac{4(\log4 + \log(\sqrt3 + \sqrt2))}{3(\log4 + \log(\sqrt3 + \sqrt2)) } $$

$$ x = \frac{4}{3}$$

A rather nice solution for what looks like a very complicated problem!